# How to rewrite index.php?main_page=xxx in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how to rewrite index.php?main_page=xxx in htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ...

/* ------- for example ------- */
www.laji.com/xxx      =>  www.laji.com/index.php?main_page=xxx
www.laji.com/xxx/     =>  www.laji.com/index.php?main_page=xxx
```

xxx can be [a-zA-Z\d] and "-" , can not be "xx.php"
I am not good at htaccess.some people helps ?
thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the htaccess file in **www.laji.com**'s document root, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?main_page=$1 [L,NC]
```